# Get user's recent media with account username instead of user ID

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I want to use the Instagram API to get a specific user's (NOT MY USER) recent media. Instagram has the following endpoint for doing so:

```
(GET) https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

This is a problem because I do not have the user's ID (*why would I, Instagram?*). What I **do** have is the account username (as most people would), e.g. @thisisauser.

I've been reading the API docs and I can't find an endpoint that will give me the user ID for a specific account username. I mean, yes, there is:

```
(GET) https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

...but it doesn't do what I need it to do, which is to search for an exact match.

I've also checked out other threads on Stack Overflow and other websites. However, the alternative solutions offered are, at best, *questionable*.

The fact that this whole thing is an actual issue surprises me. I mean, **SURELY** there's a legitimate, Instagram-approved, precise and straightforward way of either:

- obtaining a user's recent media by providing the account username (which is what people know you by... not a sequence of numbers)
  **OR**
- obtaining a user's ID via an exact match search, with no chance of multiple possible results

FYI: I'm doing this server-side, using PHP and cURL.

Side note: If I have to make a separate request to the API in order to convert an account username to a user ID, that's just a waste of a request, one more for the hourly limit. Just an observation, in case any member of the Instagram team happens to see this.

Comment: BTW: when I say "questionable", I mean methods like using a public URL from Instagram's front-end to get the user ID.

Comment: I'm on my phone ATM, I'll answer when I'm home.

Comment: Is the ID at an endpoint like https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1 what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, in that case @therock's ID would be 232192182 as returned in the JSON response. The endpoint you mentioned, however, is not listed within the Instagram API documentation and seems to be more of a front-end resource for Instagram's site.

Comment: Does `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` not return the exact match (if it exists) as the 1st result? Can't you then just grab the ID from the 1st result after confirming that it's an exact match?

Comment: Apparently there are cases where the exact match is not the first result, or isn't even there at all, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770169/instagram-api-how-to-get-user-id

Comment: It's also very wasteful (because of API rate limits) to do ANOTHER request to the API every time I need to know the ID of a different user.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all of a user's information (including the id) by requesting this URL:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

For example, this gets you all of the information related to the account taylorswift:

```
https://www.instagram.com/taylorswift/?__a=1
```

Comment: Okay, gonna have to go with this one. Having to get the user's ID through a separate request isn't optimal, but at least using this URL won't mean one less request for the API hourly limit.

Comment: by this , cannot get video files.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in the API that gets a username's media. However, by using the search endpoint, you can come up with a solution to get a user's media.

Since you're using PHP cURL, you could do something like this:

```
//this is what was returned by cURL
$response = /*what was returned by the API - see below*/

{
"data": [{
    "username": "jack",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_66_75sq.jpg",
    "id": "66",
    "last_name": "Dorsey"
},
{
    "username": "sammyjack",
    "first_name": "Sammy",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
    "id": "29648",
    "last_name": "Jack"
},
{
    "username": "jacktiddy",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
    "id": "13096",
    "last_name": "Tiddy"
}]
}

//username I am looking for
$user = 'jack';

//filter array response to find exact username you are looking for
$filter = array_filter($response,function($userdata) use ($user){
    if($userdata['username'] == $user){
        return $userdata;
    }
  });

//now use ID from filtered array to get media
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $filter['id'] . '/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can **find user id !!!**

like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + window.location.hash.substring(14),
            dataType: 'jsonp'}).done(function(response){
                 var userid = response.data.id; 
            });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and save in to your data base .then when need find it and use that way to find recent media of user :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

this way i think is beter.
you  can send a json with **php** too.

Comment: I don't think you understood. I don't need *my* user ID, I need **someone else's** user ID, and the only data I have is that person's account username. Also, I'm doing this server-side (PHP), no JavaScript.